# Why does my laptop hang after i plug in the power cord?

Tags: windows-7, windows

When plugging the power cord and starting the laptop it gets hanged during the time of windows loading so after starting the windows completely i used to connect the power cord.
the problem continued so i installed windows 7 initially having windows vista but after this the problem has increased. Even after the windows is completely loaded and the power is plugged in the laptop hangs instantly or after some time(which was not the problem in vista).
I have tried power saving mode but is not helping
When i had vista and whenever i used to swith to high performance mode or even balanced mode the laptop used to hang.

Can somebody pls help!!

Comment: Install Ubuntu or put the battery back in.

Answer (score 0):

How old is your laptop? Mine had similar problems when I would plug in a usb stick. It would just stop during bios boot. I asked around and people told me that as laptops get older the wiring inside becomes more brittle and extremely sensitive to power fluctuations. I don't think there is much you can do about it other than keep the insides of your laptop clean from dust and anything else that can interfere with the flow of electricity.

Answer (score 0):

The specific part you mentioned about it also hanging when you switch performance modes makes me wonder if this is related to graphics switching, Intel SpeedStep, or another such power management feature. I have seen laptops before where removing the power cord results in it switching to a different performance mode which causes it to briefly hang as it reconfigures. What is the model of your laptop? This may be the cause. How long does it hang for?